# Draw a process bar using android-drawable

Tags: android, android-drawable

I have a 3 register pages for a new user, we want to add a process bar of every one of the 3 states, we think about drawing shipes using android-drawable, any ideas how to implement it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Define a circle:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

   <solid 
       android:color="#F0F8FF"/>

   <size 
       android:width="120dp"
        android:height="120dp"/>
</shape>
```

Then create an horizontal ProgressBar and put 3 drawables on it.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/progress"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        style="@style/CustomProgressBarHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/q1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/light_pink_circle"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="#e6e6e6"
            android:textSize="23sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </View>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/q2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/light_pink_circle"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="2"
            android:textColor="#e6e6e6"
            android:textSize="23sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </View>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/q3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/light_pink_circle"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="3"
            android:textColor="#e6e6e6"
            android:textSize="23sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Create your ProgressBar style:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!-- Define the background properties like color etc -->
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape >
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#39bf96"
            android:centerColor="#39bf96"
            android:centerY="1.0"
            android:endColor="#39bf96"
            android:angle="270"
            />
    </shape>
</item>

<!-- Define the progress properties like start color, end color etc -->
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip android:gravity="left">
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#31a380"
                android:centerColor="#31a380"
                android:centerY="1.0"
                android:endColor="#31a380"
                android:angle="270"
                />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
```

On the first page set progress to 0, on the second to 50 and on the third to 100.